# Using ruby's BigDecimal in the C API

Tags: c, ruby, bigdecimal, ruby-c-extension

In order to create a BigDecimal from a C string in a Ruby extension, I'm doing this:

```
rb_funcall(rb_path2class("BigDecimal"), rb_intern("new"), 1, rb_str_new("0.0777", 6));
// => BigDecimal.new("0.0777")
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Also, stupid question, but is there an 'official' documentation for the C API (ruby 1.9.3), or does it just come down to reading the headers?

Comment: There's never a short way to go backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [the `initialize` function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/ext/bigdecimal#L227), and pretty much the entire `BigDecimal` C API, is declared as static and is thus not exposed.

The best way to learn about the C implementation of Ruby, and its API, is to browse [the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby), especially the [`ext` directory](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/ext). There is also the [README.EXT](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/README.EXT) file, which describes the general API.

Answer (score 2):

I do not get what the problem really is. You do like it shorter? Write a wrapper.

```
rb_object new_big_decimal(char * from) {
       rb_funcall(rb_path2class("BigDecimal"), rb_intern("new"), 1, rb_str_new(from, 6));
 }
```

Of course it may not be rb_object but something else, but what is the problem?

Comment: No problem, I just thought all the numeric types may have had macros, like how in ruby you don't need `BigDecimal.new(..)`, as `BigDecimal(..)` will suffice. Was just wondering if I was doing it wrong :)